# Getting the UTC hour from a UTC+2 datetime object

Tags: python, date

My Time string looks like this:

```
03/16/16 15:50 UTC+02:00
```

so I parse it like so

```
from dateutil import parser
my_date = parser.parse(date_string)
```

Since this is UTC+2 time, how do I convert this dateobject to UTC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`datetime.datetime.astimezone`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone) with `pytz.UTC` ([`datetime.timezone.utc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timezone.utc) if you use Python 3.x), you can get the `datetime` with UTC timezone:

```
>>> import pytz
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>>
>>> date_string = '03/16/16 15:50 UTC+02:00'
>>> my_date = parser.parse(date_string)
>>> my_date.astimezone(pytz.UTC)
datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 16, 17, 50, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```